# How do you manage the water that tomatoes generate when they're cooked?

Tags: tomatoes

I love tomatoes, and I like to put them in stuff like omelettes or to sautee them with sweet potatoes and other vegetables.

However, they "leak" so much fluid when they cook. When you sautee them in particular, they probably leak 50% of their weight in water. No matter what else you cook them with, they turn everything into a gooey mess.

What I've taken to doing is sauteeing them by themselves, then draining them, and setting them aside on a folded paper towel to absorb some water, before dumping them back into whatever else I'm cooking.

Is there a better way to do this?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. cook them some more.
2. use proper "cooking" tomatoes (for example roma variety) that contains less water.
3. remove all the pulp and seeds (the stuff between the meat) from the tomatoes before cooking them (to remove as much water as possible.

Comment: Especially #3 is vital. The pulp contains the least flavour and the most water, so it makes the biggest difference to your end result.

Comment: And always cook with the lid off